# Login to Domain http page using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to login to a local webpage using `username`, `password`, and `domain`. I have for user:

```
<input name="j_username" class="formStyle" onchange="loadDomainListForADLogin(this)" id="username" type="text">
```

For Password:

```
<input name="j_password" class="formStyle" id="password" type="password">
```

And for Domain:

```
<select name="domain" class="formStyle" onchange="checkLocalAuth(this)">
        <option>-- Choose --</option>

          <option value="1"> MYDOMAIN.NET </option>

        <option value="Local Authentication">Local Authentication</option>

      </select>
```

I followed some instruction and tried to replicate similar technique by:

```
import requests, lxml

r = requests.get('http://MyWebPage:8008')

payload = {
    "j_username": "user", 
    "j_password": "passw00rd", 
    "domain": "MYDOMAIN.NET"
}

requests.post(r, data=payload)
```

But something is not right, and code doesn't print the layout behind the login

Error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
---SNIP---
File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
requests.post(r, data=payload)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '<Response [200]>': No             schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://<Response [200]>?
```

Comment: The value for domain should be "1", not "MYDOMAIN.NET".

Comment: Even tho the domain name is hard coded in the website?

Comment: Yes.  `<option value="1"> MYDOMAIN.NET </option>` MYDOMAIN.NET is displayed onscreen, but "1" is submitted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the way you handle the url, as the request.get is triggered and the post is referencing a response obtained from the get value.
If the website needs a session to work properly you could wrap the request block as a session:

```
import requests, lxml
url = 'http://MyWebPage:8008'

s = requests.Session()

payload = {
    "j_username": "user", 
    "j_password": "passw00rd", 
    "domain": "MYDOMAIN.NET"
}

s.post(url, data=payload)
```

Comment: So this actually looks good, I get no errors, thanks for that. But somehow It doesn't scrape the content behind the login parameters

Comment: @uzdisral as it doesn't read the values for 'j_username' and 'j_password'?

Comment: That's pretty much what it looks like, as if it was ignoring the payload @pypalms

Comment: @uzdisral It may then be an issue with the backing web process, or it is looking for different parameters. Some processes look for the user/password as headers? Could try passing the payload as a header

Comment: I can try capture the traffic in wireshark. Thanks for the tips tho, I appreciate it